# Bootstrap button with text distributed in two lines with different font size at each line

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a button in a web site.

This is the current button code:

```
<a href="pickupdeliverypu.php" class="button  button-rounded" style=" margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: center;color: #fff; background-color: #ff6600">Start Using Pickup & Delivery</a>
```

And this is the current output:

[image]

I would like to change the button as follows:

[image]

But I am not able to get the text with different font size at each button text line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `br` tag, which would look something like this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="m-4">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">
    <span style="font-size:18px">Order Online</span><br/>
    <span style="font-size:10px">Delivery &amp; Pickup</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

You can then also adjust the `line-height` of the `br` tag. Or assign classes instead of inline styling.

Comment: @mvasco no problem... Cheers!